# Laravel ORM "with" is returning all rows even with constraint

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM, any idea why the following is pulling every row instead of just the one I'm asking for (book_id=3)?

```
    if ($Book = Book::find(3)) {
        return (Book::with(array('chapters.pages' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->where('book_id', '=', 3 ); // hard-coded id for illustration purposes
                    })
            )->get()->toJson());
    }
```

The output I'm getting is every single book with every chapter and every page. I only want to pull that single book with chapters and pages.

According to the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) I should be able to add a constraint. Seems like I'm following the docs pretty closely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should "return ($Book::with(..."  be "return (Book::with(..."? i.e. without the $

Comment: The line above it assigns an ORM object to the variable $Book, but I can actually use Book::with(...) as well. Just tried it, same results. I'll update the question.

Comment: can you post some of your chapters model, and also the schema for book, chapters and pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are asking for `Book::with()` - but you have not put a constraint on the Book() itself. So you need to do `Book::with()->where()`

Does this work

```
Book::with(array('chapters.pages' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->where('book_id', '=', 3 ); // hard-coded id for illustration purposes
                    })
            )->where('id', '=', '3')->get()->toJson());
```

note the `->where()` - which is putting the id constraint on the query.

**Edit:** if you have correctly defined relationships (such as HasMany() etc) - then this should work:

```
$books = Book::with('chapters.pages')->where('id', '=', '3')->get();
```

Because the relationship with mean it only gets the 'chapters/pages' for the book with id of 3 by defintion.

Comment: Well I'll be darned, it worked! Not sure how I missed that where(). Sometimes you just need a second set of eyeballs. Thank you!

Comment: fyi, you are correct about the simpler version. There was no need for the $query->where() once I added with()->where().